# How to connect Cognito to use AWS SES to send verification emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses

I have successfully connected AWS Cognito to AWS SES but I get error messages from Cognito when users register on my app that SES is limited to sending emails to only verified emails.
I have messaged AWS support to remove limitations on SES but it was denied, I explained that i was only swnding verification emails from Cognito yet it was denied.
My question is if there another way to connect Cognito to other AWS Services that could send this verification emails to users upon registration.

I messaged AWS support to remove limitation on my SES but I was denied.

Answer (score 0):

I would continue to follow-up with AWS support to continue working through any challenges and/or requirements needed on your part in order to send emails through SES. It sounds like you're still in the SES sandbox, hence the restrictions. Just in case, here's some the resources to help (in case you have not seen these yet):

- [Email settings for Amazon Cognito user pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-email.html#user-pool-email-configure)
- [Moving out of the Amazon SES sandbox](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/request-production-access.html)

Otherwise, Amazon Cognito has support for something called a [Custom email sender Lambda trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html). This may be an option to explore, but this requires you to integrate with a any email provider of your choice. To my knowledge, SES is the only email service provider from AWS.

Comment: I am aware of the sandbox, I messaged them already but my request was declined, can I connect this custom email sender lambda trigger with an external email provider like MailChimp?

Comment: @Wiley not being difficult, but AWS usually doesn't just decline this type of request. They usually provide a reason- typically some required info is missing. 

Otherwise, are you saying after following **all instructions** in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/request-production-access.html), you're only getting a "decline" response?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with MailChimp, but if they provide an API to send emails, then in theory this should work. You will need to test. In addition to the shared custom email send Lambda trigger link, this might be helpful: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cognito-custom-email-sender-trigger